# Checkout Totals Sort order not changing

Tags: magento2, database, backend

When I attempt to change the checkout totals sort order in Magento 2 backend, I can press save, however the sort order doesn't seem changed from the magento 2 backend.

When I look in the database, the following appears:

```
    MariaDB [mag]> SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%totals_sort%";
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                          | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+
|      1095 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/subtotal    | 1     |
|      1096 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/discount    | 2     |
|      1097 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/shipping    | 3     |
|      1098 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/tax         | 5     |
|      1099 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/weee        | 4     |
|      1100 | default |        0 | sales/totals_sort/grand_total | 6     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This does not correspond with the details shown in Magento 2 backend.

Subtotal
1

Discount
3

Shipping
2

Tax 
5

Fixed Product Tax
4

Grand Total 
6

The email hasn't changed either.
Does anyone have any idea?